# Which will be better rest API url according to rest standard?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, api-design

I have package as resource. A package can have parent package and so on. On top of hierarchy is the root package. Now the use case is:

Given a packageId of any package (not necessarily root package), I want to retrieve details of the root package that exists in its hierarchy at top.

I am confused between 2 urls : (or any other which is better)

```
/rest/v1/packageDetails/rootPackage/{packageId}
```

Or

```
/rest/v1/packageDetails/{packageId}/rootPackage
```

what should be the most suitable rest end point url ?

Comment: Couldn't you say that, from a REST perspective, 'rootPackage' **then becomes** the package ID of the root package? Therefore the only question here is "should all my IDs be numeric?", and that's opinion-based

Comment: Per @CassioMazzochiMolin, REST doesn't have any standards, guidelines, suggestions, or advice on what URLs should look like. REST considers URLs as opaque identifiers, not contextualized pathways.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 2**. To demonstrate reasoning, I will use a different example.

Lets say you have a rest API endpoint:

`/rest/v1/users/{userId}`

If you wanted to create an additional endpoint to retrieve a subset of data, for example `attributes`, you would structure it like so:

`/rest/v1/users/{userId}/attributes`

Another use case to retrieve a specific attribute for a user may look like:

`/rest/v1/users/{userId}/attributes/{attributeId}`

The important thing to note, is that the attributes **belong** to the user. The attribute is one or many bits of data that are owned by a specific user.

In your case, a package has-a rootPackage, so you can model rootPackage as belonging to a specific package.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

REST is an architectural style and not a cookbook for designing URIs. Now, if you want to stick to *REST standards*, then you should consider *hypermedia*.

### Long answer

Assuming that there's a REST standard for designing URIs for your resources is a **misconception**: *REST doesn't enforce or suggests any URI design*.

The URI syntax is defined in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and this is the document you should consider when designing URIs. As general rule, the path is organized in *hierarchical* form (with segments separated by `/`) and can contain non-hierarchical data in the query component (starting with `?`).

If I understand your issue correctly, you could simply use `/rest/v1/packageDetails/{packageId}` to identify a package.

Then use **hypermedia** to link to other packages. You can provide [links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288) in the header or in the response payload. In a JSON payload, for instance, you could have:

```
{
  "id": "foo",
  "content": {...},
  "_links":{
    "self":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/packageDetails/foo"
    },
    "root":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/packageDetails/bar"
    },
    "parent":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/packageDetails/biz"
    },
    "children":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/packageDetails/foo/children"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your options is strictly right. Why:

1. For option one, `/rest/v1/packageDetails/rootPackage/{packageId}` would be supposed to be the URI of what will be returned. But the ID on this URI will be that of a child of the resource that will be returned.
2. For a similar reason, option 2's URI, `/rest/v1/packageDetails/{packageId}/rootPackage` will suppose that `rootPackage` is a sub-resource of `/rest/v1/packageDetails/{packageId}`, which is absurd as we'd be locating a parent under its child.

A third option that I personally would add and recommend is to simply use a search with a client-defined level (in the package hierarchy):

```
/rest/v1/packageDetails/?childId=packageId&level=0
```

This would return the top-level package in the tree where `packageId` is located. I used `level=0` as an example of a field indicating the position of the package in its own hierarchy.

With your good understanding of resources, you can choose a more appropriate name or type, but I believe this is a better option.